# node js webpack Undefined envioronment variable

Tags: node.js, express, webpack

HHHi,

I'm trying to use the .env file to store the API id and key for the API I'm using and it's not working.  My .env file is in the root of my working directory as well as the root of the repository where the .gitignore file is.  It looks like this:

```
API_ID=XXXXXX
API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

I installed dotenv and in my index.js file in my server directory I call it like this:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
```

then in my apiCall.js function I try to call the variables from the .env file like this:

```
const AYLIENTextAPI = require('aylien_textapi');

let textapi = new AYLIENTextAPI({
    application_id: process.env.API_ID,
    application_key: process.env.API_KEY
});
```

but the ID and Key are showing up as undefined.  What am I doing wrong?  I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Mike

UPDATE:

this is my webpack.dev.js file:

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/client/index.js',
    output : {
        libraryTarget: 'var',
        library: 'Client'
    },
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    stats: 'verbose',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: '/\.js$/',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader' ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: "./src/client/views/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html",
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // Simulate the removal of files
            dry: true,
            // Write Logs to Console
            verbose: true,
            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,
            protectWebpackAssets: false
        })
    ]
}
```

this is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "example-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/server/index.js",
    "build-prod": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js",
    "build-dev": "webpack  --config webpack.dev.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "",
  "dependencies": {
    "aylien_textapi": "^0.7.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.6",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^1.1.3",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your .env file is in project root folder. If your .env file is in root folder and still you are getting undefined, then try using
 require('dotenv').config({path: __dirname + '/.env'})

Comment: thhat didn't work.  any other idea?

Comment: Can you update the question with your  ```webpack.config.js``` and ```package.json```?

Comment: ok i posted them.  does that help?

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.  I can only access the environment variables on the server side.